# How to skip validation on regeneration of secure token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

So I'm sending out password reset e-mails and I've hit a stump on how to solve this issue, so after the user has reset their password. I regenerate a new password reset token (I know this is bad, before I had it generate when I was sending out the password reset request, but that didn't work so I tried this.). Every time I regenerate the token it does not skip validations that I have set in the model.

As said before, I have tried switching it around, regenerating a new token before I send the e-mail and now after they have reset their password. I have also looked the documentation of `has_secure_token` and I don't see anywhere where I can skip validation when I regenerate a token.

This is my code for resetting the password in the `User` model.

```
def reset_password(password)
  self.regenerate_reset_password_token
  self.password = password
  save(:validate => false)
end
```

I'm getting the error for validating my user's passwords, when regenerating the token, as said before not sure how to skip the validation when regenerating the token on line 2 of the code above.

`Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
def generate_password_reset_token
  self.reset_password_token = generate_token
  self.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now
  save!
end


def generate_token
  SecureRandom.base58(5)
end
```

Comment: This is one of the approaches that I thought of doing, but I thought it would be bad code / practice as I already have a way to perform the generation, I might just remove the has_secure_token and use SecureRandom.base58(24), as it does. Thanks!

Comment: So did it worked? If yes please do accept the answer thanks